# What are the differences between an ISRs Interrupt Service Routines and conventional Code?

Tags: operating-system

I tried to find a proper answer but couldn't find any , and i need to know what are the issues that must be considered in the implementation of a set of ISRs in any system.

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: sorry i mean proper *

Comment: You're question is vague. Do you mean the ISR's that are found in microcontrollers? Or OS interrupts? What are you trying to implement/understand?

Comment: No i mean the ISRs in OS interrupts,im trying to understand the diffrences between ISRs and conventional Code !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An interrupt service routine (duh!) services an "interrupt".  An "interrupt" is pretty much that -- the execution of "normal" code is interrupted (for any of a multitude of reasons) and control is passed to a service routine which has no real relationship to/knowledge of the previously-executing code (even if that code caused the interrupt somehow).

Keep in mind that interrupts can occur at many "levels" -- very low-level ISRs may handle unimplemented instructions (eg, a "sqrt" instruction in an FPU that doesn't support that function) and simulate that functionality.  They may handle device I/O (totally unrelated to the executing code), page faults, program errors, etc.

Typically (it varies with processor, OS, and type of interrupt) the ISR is entered with only a bare minimum of the "processor state" saved, so the ISR must first save enough state (additional GPRs, status registers, etc) until it has enough free to carry out its function.  Typically the saving will be into a pre-allocated "interrupt save area", unless the interrupt is "high level" enough to allow the ISR to be pageable, in which case the top of the stack may be used.

Then the ISR must carry out its function, being careful to limit itself to available resources (eg, using only "pinned" storage if not in a pageable state).

Finally, the ISR must restore the interrupted environment and return, or, if the interrupt is to be converted into an exception, create the corresponding exception-signalling environment and signal the exception.

Comment: thanks dude , but your answer didn't match the my question ,,appreciate your cooperation

Comment: The (unique) issues revolve mainly around appreciating that the routine is running in a *very* restricted environment, and therefore many common coding techniques cannot be used -- no exceptions, no paging, sometimes not even any RAM, just registers.  If a high-level language is used extreme care must be exercised to prevent it from doing things it shouldn't.